# TypeScript: typing a mock function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I created a simple helper mock function. I'm currently struggling with getting the types right. Here is what I have so far:

```
import includes from 'ramda/src/includes';

function fn<T, Y extends any[]> (implementation: ((...args: Y) => T) = () => {}) {
  const mockFn = (...args: Y) => {
    mockFn.calls.push(args);
    return implementation(...args);
  };
  mockFn.calls = [];

  mockFn.hasBeenCalled = () => mockFn.calls.length > 0;
  mockFn.hasBeenCalledWith = (...args: Y) => includes(args, mockFn.calls);

  return mockFn;
}
```

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBMAdgYwDYFcAmBTAznAMyghDgHIoBDETSgelymTqTSzzIG4Aobg9FDGAREhRAB4AKgBo4ATTjYAHjGyJM+SogCeAbQC6APjgAKUGFTYQamJSEiAXKZMA6N5SgBzXE7kBKOABeY0kAwNMw4wBvAF8AqO44OGQRXHgQCGQAawAxUXDXdy8feUi4BKSkjOy8l2RKVFRcFzB0XAALEw9vPx5KuChsGHQoUXNLa0Rbe0RCl27cXsS4GL64atzEOoamoLgDHmWN2vbKXAAhbDUAYR3sTD2TMuOt+sbmy0RPGHa4YwAGNYvFynC5XRC3Rr3ADqwB+jzc82KvjKrAwOFwXWKsmBbyaS2Wg2Go3WmU2PBi3CAA) is a playground example.

TypeScript complains at two places.

Firstly, it complains about `implementation` saying:

```
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type '(...args: Y) => T'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.
```

Secondly, it complains about `mockFn.calls` that

```
Member 'calls' implicitly has an 'any[]' type.
```

The mocked function should be used like this:

```
// with implementation
const originalFunction = (a: number, b: number) => a + b; // e.g. a simple add function
const mockedFn = fn(originalFunction);

mockedFn.hasBeenCalled();
// false

mockedFn(21, 21);
// 42

mockedFn.hasBeenCalled();
// true

mockedFn.hasBeenCalledWith(21);
// false

mockedFn.hasBeenCalledWith(21, 21);
// true
```

But it should also work without implementation (hence the default to `() => {}`).

```
const mockFn = fn();

// etc.
```

It would be cool if TypeScript could know that `mockedFn` has the same function signature as `originalFunction`, but additionally exposing `.calls`, `hasBeenCalled` and `hasBeenCalledWith`.

In my current implementation, it seems to know about `hasBeenCalled` and `hasBeenCalledWith` saying they are of type:

```
mockFn.hasBeenCalled(): boolean
mockFn.hasBeenCalledWith(...args: Y): boolean
```

How can I fix these type errors so that TypeScript knows about `fn`s capabilities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use single generic parameter representing the function and use [Parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) and [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) utilities with it:

```
function fn<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> (implementation?: T) {
  const mockFn = (...args: Parameters<T>): ReturnType<T> => {
    mockFn.calls.push(args);
    return implementation?.(...args);
  };
  mockFn.calls = [] as (Parameters<T>)[];

  mockFn.hasBeenCalled = () => mockFn.calls.length > 0;
  mockFn.hasBeenCalledWith = (...args: Parameters<T>) => includes(args, mockFn.calls);

  return mockFn;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXy3QmVAGcAKAOmtgHNSAueKVATwG0BdASiYCMcOCCBYBuALAAoKSnTY8SVAB4AKvBAAPDCFTBS8KjRj0mLDj3gBeAHzM218lgC2AB2FOdGKPNQB%20Jirc8ADeUvDwYHikGPBOOGAA1gBi%20JYG1JR0jPAACrBQHtowpKrWvPAASiAYyDCoKqwuIKVWtqGS4eFxiSmUYFAQEKSULsikABbkWdwSHZ1wNXUEru6e3rh%20lIaZxqQzYfAAvrNd8cmofQNDVvBczPrkeTAF1SDFpdxcovBSB93nlHGUFIACEQDoAMJXEDAG7kII2WJnXr9QbDYSoWgYcbwWwABhOSJ6FyBoPBqChgxhAHUsNi4Rkskwni8iiUVGVWgQiCQQBQsgAaIkA1FDfbSOYLWr4f4pWaHX4SyKoaLwHAwLC0QgDJJoTAbOFQJioZBOPhvIV8Y2m80wBG2KDwADU8D43wA9O71JRaJRmPBSM43AgoMBYbJ9XgpMrVf8YSkbohUOR1ZrtRBdXINuKpHHgL1SWDIdDgPDZp6kANSCBFXmUuQAEwARiFzfFFYALA3a2d4yTgUWKSWy1IKxgYMgaxK6-2ycWqcBadjG03217EFWp7ne-nZ4PKcJF3TJs3W6vZtGojFZalFGWgA)

---

First error says that it is possible to call function with explicit generic parameters (e.g. `fn<number, []>()`) and the default value (`() => {}`) won't supply the required return type. To fix this optional chaining was used instead of default value